# converting gant build scripts into ant scripts

Tags: grails, ant, msbuild, gant

I am pressmuming (without really knowing) that "gant" is superior to "ant", especially when building grails applications. I have some old, inherited, grails apps using ant. Is is possible or easy to convert existing build.xml files into gant build scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [ANT2GANT](http://dist.codehaus.org/gant/distributions/ant2gant-0.1.2)

> If you have a go at using it, please
>   feel free to give feedback and/or make
>   bug reports and improvement requests
>   via the Gant JIRA.
>
> The project for this script is being
>   maintained as a Bazaar branch.  The
>   URL for the branch is
>   http://www.russel.org.uk/Bazaar/Ant2Gant
>   **, though if you want to browse the material rather than branch is you may
>   well want to use the URL
>   http://www.russel.org.uk:8080/Ant2Gant.ttp://www.russel.org.uk:8080/Ant2Gant.

Comment: Mads, considering that your answer is the only one, and your answer intriguing, I award you the prize! I'll love to help whenever I have a chance.